# How to fix "Delete Message" Error in android studio java (Chat Application)?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a function for delete a message in my chat application via the setOnLongClickListener() method but unfortunately I can not delete the message so plaese check it properly and give me the solution

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MessageModel messageModel = messageModels.get(position);

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Delete")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this message?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                                String senderRoom = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()+recId;
                                database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderRoom)
                                        .child(messageModel.getMessage())
                                        .setValue(null);

                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();

                return false;
            }
        });

         if(holder.getClass()== SenderViewHolder.class){
             ((SenderViewHolder)holder).senderMsg.setText(messageModel.getMessage());
         }else {
             ((ReceiverViewHolder)holder).receiverMsg.setText(messageModel.getMessage());
         }
    }
```

Even if I click the "Yes" option in the popup message then still I can't delete the message

[image: Popup message with Yes and No option but It is not working]

Comment: Did you debug your code? I'd suspect this is a problem with how you're using firebase instead of the UI.

Comment: Yeh I think it's correct but I can't find the issue so how can I fix this please help me

Comment: What research did you do? A quick google search (since I'm not a firebase user) shows that there's `removeValue()` so maybe try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderRoom).child(messageModel.getMessage()).setValue(null);
```

to

```
database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderRoom).child(messageModel.getMessage()).getRef().removeValue();
```